# Why values of vector of Utf8Char is changing?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have one CSVReader class, which has this function

```
vector<UtfChar*> CSVFile::ReadFile(FILE* fp)
{
    //int count = 0;
    Utf8Char buff[256];

    fgets(buff, 256, (FILE*)fp);
      //  count++;

    Utf8Char *token = strtok(buff, ",");
    bvector<UtfChar*> localVec;
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        localVec.push_back(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }
    return localVec;
}
```

Now I have another class, from which I am calling this function:

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("SampleFile.csv", "r");
while((getc(fp)) != EOF)
{
    bvector<Utf8Char*> localVec = csvFile.ReadFile(fp);  
}
```

Here i am comparing values of `localVec` with some set of values (`char*`) I have. But in this other class, when I am trying to access vector like `localVec[0]` or l`ocalVec[1]`, it is giving a garbage.
I tried with comparison in CSVReader class itself, then its working there. But I need to do comparison in other class, so that i can use same CSVReader class for other CSV Files.

Comment: Pointers and C functions. What can go wrong? It's because you're using one buffer, all vector elements reference it and then it gets destroyed. Please, use C++ standard library.

Comment: What kind of "Garbage" does it give? How is Utf8Char defined?

Comment: @LogicStuff If a programmer can't learn the scope of local variables and how to handle simple pointers, using the C++ standard library isn't going to help.

Comment: What's a `bvector`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is you have dangling pointers.  You create and populate a local array with

```
Utf8Char buff[256];

fgets(buff, 256, (FILE*)fp);
```

Then you get pointers to the different segments of that buffer with

```
Utf8Char *token = strtok(buff, ",");
bvector<UtfChar*> localVec;
while (token != NULL)
{
    localVec.push_back(token);
    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
}
```

So now you have a vector full of pointers to each segment of the local buffer.  After you return the vector from the function the local buffer gets destroyed.  This means all the pointers you have now point to memory you no longer own.  Using those pointers is undefined behavior and is the reason you get the garbage output.

Also note you can avoid all of these C-ism's if you use [How can I read and parse CSV files in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c) to parse the CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

This code

```
bvector<UtfChar*> localVec;
```

means you're storing *pointers* in your vector.

Those pointers **point to a local variable** that goes out of scope when your function returns.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you skip the first char in each string read from the file:

```
while((getc(fp)) != EOF){
    bvector<Utf8Char*> localVec = csvFile.ReadFile(fp);
}
```

Is it intentional? If it is, then here lies the problem: UTF-8 characters can have variable length (e.g. some are represented with 1 byte, others with 2 bytes and so on, up to 6 bytes). If you don't do any string conversion, you can copy UTF-8 string byte by byte from one place to another and not worry about characters lengths, because the string will remain valid. But if you slice off the first byte off the string, then it stop being a valid UTF-8 string and cannot be interpreted like it.

Comment: No its not intentional. How to avoid it.. thanks BTW